# How to get the aggregate of the records up to the current record using polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

Given a dataset with records of an event where the event can happen multiple times for the same ID I want to find the aggregate of the previous records of that ID. Let's say I have the following table:

| id | datetime | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 20230101T00:00 | 2 |
| 123 | 20230101T01:00 | 5 |
| 123 | 20230101T03:00 | 7 |
| 123 | 20230101T04:00 | 1 |
| 456 | 20230201T04:00 | 1 |
| 456 | 20230201T07:00 | 1 |
| 456 | 20230205T04:00 | 1 |

I want to create a new column "agg" that adds the previous values of "value" found for that same record to get the following table:

| id | datetime | value | agg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 20230101T00:00 | 2 | 0 |
| 123 | 20230101T01:00 | 5 | 2 |
| 123 | 20230101T03:00 | 7 | 7 |
| 123 | 20230101T04:00 | 1 | 14 |
| 456 | 20230201T04:00 | 1 | 0 |
| 456 | 20230201T07:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 456 | 20230205T04:00 | 1 | 2 |

[Polars documentation](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/expressions/window/) says there is a window function but it is not clear how to collect just the previous values of the current record. I know it is possible to do this with PySpark using:

```py
window = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('datetime').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)

(
    df_pyspark
    .withColumn('agg', f.sum('value').over(window).cast('int'))
    .fillna(0, subset=['agg'])
)
```

---

EDIT: Apparently there is no trivial way to execute this code using polars as it is being discussed in an open [issue 8976](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/8976) in the polars' repository.

---

EDIT: Fixed the expected table after aplying the window function

Comment: I thought it would be `df.with_columns(agg = pl.col('value').shift().cumsum().over('id'))` but I don't follow why the last `123` has `0` and the first `456` has `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description sounds like `.shift().cumsum().over()`

```
df = pl.from_repr("""
┌─────┬─────────────────────┬───────┐
│ id  ┆ datetime            ┆ value │
│ --- ┆ ---                 ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ datetime[ns]        ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪═════════════════════╪═══════╡
│ 123 ┆ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2     │
│ 123 ┆ 2023-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ 5     │
│ 123 ┆ 2023-01-01 03:00:00 ┆ 7     │
│ 123 ┆ 2023-01-01 04:00:00 ┆ 1     │
│ 456 ┆ 2023-02-01 04:00:00 ┆ 1     │
│ 456 ┆ 2023-02-01 07:00:00 ┆ 1     │
│ 456 ┆ 2023-02-05 04:00:00 ┆ 1     │
└─────┴─────────────────────┴───────┘
""")
```

```
df.with_columns(agg = pl.col('value').shift().cumsum().over('id'))
```

```
shape: (7, 4)
┌─────┬─────────────────────┬───────┬──────┐
│ id  ┆ datetime            ┆ value ┆ agg  │
│ --- ┆ ---                 ┆ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ datetime[ns]        ┆ i64   ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪═════════════════════╪═══════╪══════╡
│ 123 ┆ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2     ┆ null │
│ 123 ┆ 2023-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ 5     ┆ 2    │
│ 123 ┆ 2023-01-01 03:00:00 ┆ 7     ┆ 7    │
│ 123 ┆ 2023-01-01 04:00:00 ┆ 1     ┆ 14   │
│ 456 ┆ 2023-02-01 04:00:00 ┆ 1     ┆ null │
│ 456 ┆ 2023-02-01 07:00:00 ┆ 1     ┆ 1    │
│ 456 ┆ 2023-02-05 04:00:00 ┆ 1     ┆ 2    │
└─────┴─────────────────────┴───────┴──────┘
```

`.over()` in polars is essentially a groupby operation:

```
(df.groupby('id', maintain_order=True)
   .agg(
      pl.exclude('id'),
      agg = pl.col('value').shift().cumsum()
   )
)
```

```
shape: (2, 4)
┌─────┬───────────────────────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ datetime                          ┆ value       ┆ agg             │
│ --- ┆ ---                               ┆ ---         ┆ ---             │
│ i64 ┆ list[datetime[ns]]                ┆ list[i64]   ┆ list[i64]       │
╞═════╪═══════════════════════════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 123 ┆ [2023-01-01 00:00:00, 2023-01-01… ┆ [2, 5, … 1] ┆ [null, 2, … 14] │
│ 456 ┆ [2023-02-01 04:00:00, 2023-02-01… ┆ [1, 1, 1]   ┆ [null, 1, 2]    │
└─────┴───────────────────────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────────┘
```